# Time complexity of inserting in to a heap

Tags: algorithm, heap, time-complexity

I am trying to mostly understand the reasoning behind the Big O and Omega of inserting a new element in a heap. I know I can find answers online but I really like having a thorough understanding rather than just finding answers online and just memorizing blindly.

So for instance if we have the following heap (represented in array format)

```
 [8,6,7,3,5,3,4,1,2]
```

If we decide to insert a new element "4" our array will look like this now

```
 [8,6,7,3,5,3,4,1,2,4]
```

It would be placed in index 9 and since this is a 0th index based array its parent would be index 4 which is element 5. In this case we would not need to do anything because 4 is < 5 and it does not violate the binary heap property. So best case is OMEGA(1).

However if the new element we insert is 100 then we would have to call the max-heapify function which has running time of O(log n) and therefore in the worst case inserting a new element in the heap takes O(log n).

Can someone correct me if I am wrong because I am not sure if my understanding or reasoning is 100%?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But do you know why is inserting to heap O(log n) and what does that mean?

Comment: It would help if you can explain , i might not have correct understanding...

Comment: I think your understanding of "max-heapify" is incorrect or may be misleading. The max-heapify function, e.g., in CLRS defines max-heapify as a function that checks whether properties of a heap is satisfied at the input index. This is always a top down procedure. When you're inserting at the leaf, you need to recursively check whether parent-child properties are violated, and that's a bottom up procedure. So the two are not the same thing, though maybe there are notes out there that define max-heapify as a bottom up procedure, but usually I just see them named "Heapify_up" and "Heapify_down"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you are right about the best-case running time. And for the worst-case running time, you are also right that this is Theta(lg n) and the reason why is that your heap is always assumed to be BALANCED, i.e. every height level set of nodes is full except at the bottom level. So when you insert an element at the bottom level and swap from one level up to the next level in your heap, the number of nodes at that level is cut roughly in half and so you can only do this swap log_2(n) = O(lg n) times before you are at the root node (i.e. the level at the top of the heap that has just one node). And if you insert a value that belongs at the top of the heap, initially at the bottom of the heap then you will indeed have to do basically log_2(n) swaps to get the element to the top of the heap where it belongs.. So the number of swaps in the worst case is Theta(lg n).

Comment: This is off-topic but I never understood Theta, Omega.
Using your comment as an example - how is the worst-case running time is Theta(lg n) here?
and referring original question text - how is best case is OMEGA(1).?

Please also share some good article or video if have on the same

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct.
Since the heap has a complete binary tree structure, its height = lg n (where n is no of elements). 
In the worst case (element inserted at the bottom has to be swapped at every level from bottom to top up to the root node to maintain the heap property), 1 swap is needed on every level. Therefore, the maximum no of times this swap is performed is log n.
Hence, insertion in a heap takes O(log n) time.

Comment: "nearly complete"